# Problems using a validation rule with a REGEX component

Tags: salesforce

I have validation rule that does not validate as true, and I can't see why is does not.  The formula is as follows:

```
AND( 
$RecordType.Name = "GSM Yfirsýn", 
INCLUDES( mplGSM_Yfirlit_Extras__c , "Netið"), 
REGEX(LEFT( txPayerKennitala__c ,1), "[4-6] {1}") 
)
```

It looks for the specific Record Type, checks to see whether any selected values from the multi-select picklist mplGSM_Yfirlit_Extras_*c contain the word 'Netið' and also does a regex check on whether the first letter of the text string contained in txPayerKennitala*_c is either 4,5 or 6.  If those are all true it should be triggered.  But it isn't.  I'm thinking that the REGEX part of is misconfigured.  I can do this - use a LEFT() action to check the first letter and then pass that to the REGEX function that validates ?  Or am I off-base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your REGEX `[4-6] {1}` contains a space before the `{1}`. It's validating that there's a number 4, 5, or 6, and one space, but comparing only the LEFT first character of `txPayerKennitala__c`. Change your REGEX to `[4-6]{1}`, and see if that helps.

Comment: Yeah, it did.  I'm, still not getting this to work, but it's a step in the right direction.  Thanks for that.  I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I modified this rule like so:

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work just fine.  The REGEX part started working when i removed the space.  My problems stemmed also from the INCLUDES part.  I had 5 different values in the multi-select picklist to evaluate and I had to use an OR statement between them.  So for anyone who stumbles into this this was the correct rule formula for me:

```
AND( 
$RecordType.Name = "GSM Yfirsýn", 
OR( 
INCLUDES(mplGSM_Yfirlit_Extras__c ,"Netið í Símann 1" ), 
INCLUDES(mplGSM_Yfirlit_Extras__c ,"Netið í Símann 2" ), 
INCLUDES(mplGSM_Yfirlit_Extras__c ,"Netið í Símann 3" ), 
INCLUDES(mplGSM_Yfirlit_Extras__c ,"Netið í Símann 4" ), 
INCLUDES(mplGSM_Yfirlit_Extras__c ,"Netið í Símann 5" )), 
REGEX(LEFT( txPayerKennitala__c ,1),"[4-6]{1}") 
)
```